# How exactly git-remote-dropbox works in stack with docker-compose secrets?

Tags: git, docker, dropbox, docker-secrets

I am building docker-compose service where I want to download my project files remotely from Dropbox. Usually I use this bridge to use my Dropbox stored project for git purposes - https://github.com/anishathalye/git-remote-dropbox.

What it does, after authorization it basically creates a file called `.git-remote-dropbox.json` which contains credentials for git to automatically login into Dropbox account after what it can be used to version control projects which are situated at Dropbox (At least as I see it).

However, when I try to put my `.git-remote-dropbox.json` file as a secret into my `docker-compose.yml` file, later on it is unable to download the project because I am not authorized. The secret part in `docker-compose.yml` looks like this:

```
secrets:
  dropboxlogin:
    file: ~/.git-remote-dropbox.json
```

If anyone ever worked with such a bizarre stack, I would gladly take a helping hand here, because I am unsure why it's not working as supposed.

Comment: A couple questions: 1. Have you tested everything works w/out using secrets, and then add the secrets part when it's confirmed working? 2. If yes, have you tried using a full path to the secret rather than the `~`?

Comment: It does not work without secrets either. It even does not work as intended when I try to use "git remote dropbox login" command on my own PC as I found out. It only automatically works via Webstorm somehow allowing to pull/push updates to dropbox repo. I am still unsure if it creates a secret file or not, will try to use full path for it